# Unable to Center (Android) GridView Items using android:layout_gravity="center"

Tags: android, gridview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm attempting to center items in a GridView using `android:layout_gravity="center"` however they continually appear pushed up against the left edge and I cannot seem to spot what I have done wrong in this instance.

[image]

### XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ListView_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/boxart" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:rowCount="4" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="Button" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="Button" />
        </GridLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try android:gravity="center"

Comment: I updated it as suggested... it still does not seem to appear centered: 

http://imgur.com/5ug7qpC

http://pastebin.com/UygKQTxF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your `GridLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout` hence `android:layout_gravity="center"` doesn't work [0].

Try replacing that with one of these (as your center preference):

- `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`
- `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`
- `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

[0] - [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) you can find all the layout parameters a `RelativeLayout` supports. `layout_gravity` is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can gridview attribute numcolumns.

```
<GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"/>
```

Comment: I updated it as suggested... it still does not seem to appear centered: 

http://imgur.com/5ug7qpC

http://pastebin.com/UygKQTxF

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code, it works for me:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="100dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

One difference to note:

android:gravity : sets the gravity of the content of the View its used on.

android:layout_gravity : sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its parent.

Comment: I updated it as suggested... it still does not seem to appear centered: 

http://imgur.com/5ug7qpC

http://pastebin.com/UygKQTxF

Comment: Can you try updating the main Linear Layout height as match_parent and Relative layout width(grid view's parent) as match_parent too? Instead of wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

In RelativeLayout you should use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` instead of `android:layout_gravity="center"` and in your GridLayout change your `android:layout_width="match_parent"`
to
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.
if you want to changing spaces between buttons you can add `android:layout_margin="10dp"` to button tag easily.
I hope be happy :D

Comment: I did as you suggested.... it still appears to be centered to the left for some strange reason :( 

http://pastebin.com/7AX9ibM4

http://imgur.com/DjYmbbx

Comment: Just should assign android:layout_centerInParent="true" to element in RelativeLayout instead of itself :)